# How to notice, when fragment animation after popBackStack is done?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I´m working with "android.support.v4.Fragment"´s, and the animation I´m doing this way...

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStack();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);

ImageView ivStart = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivStart);
ivStart.setColorFilter(Color.rgb(80, 80, 80), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

ll_content_frame.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

String itemName = "";
if (position <= (dataList.size() - 1))
  itemName = (dataList.get(position)).getItemName();

if (itemName.equalsIgnoreCase(PResText.getString("Inputs_Outputs"))) {
  DigIO digIO = new DigIO();
  ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, digIO, DigIO.TAG);
  ft.addToBackStack(DigIO.TAG);
  ft.commit();
  fm.executePendingTransactions();
}
.
.
```

XML like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    >
</translate>
```

Now I´m trying to notice with a listener or something else, when fade_out animation, started within onBackPressed() by popBackStack(), is being done.

I´ve tried this code... by extending my fragments from these class.

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MyFragment";

@Override
public Animation onCreateAnimation(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {

Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), nextAnim);

anim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Animation started.");
    // additional functionality
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Animation repeating.");
    // additional functionality
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Animation ended.");
    // additional functionality
  }
});

return anim;
}
}
```

but this listener only responds at fade_in animation.

Kind regards proto

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about this matter a while back. If I understand right, you want to know when the **Fragment is finished**. From FragmentManager, you can get the Fragment. Certainly you know which Fragment you're interested.

My suggestion is to override Fragment methods, either `onDetach`() or `onDestroy`(), occurs before onDetach.

Comment: ...and notify proper listener, implemented for example by Activity.